# AC Brotherhood - Completing all of subject 16's puzzles

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I completed the game first before I completed all of Subject 16's puzzles. When I run around on subject 16's secret level I reach a dead end where nothing happens and there is no further place to free-run to.

Is this meant to happen? Or have I done something wrong? I have to re-load my last save to continue from where I left off in Rome.

Comment: Hint: the level changes while you play it. Try to figure out when and how to control it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too completed the game before solving all his puzzles. You should be able to go through 16's secret level anyways, but keep in mind it is a maze. So if you reach a dead end, you'll need to find another route. It took me a few tries, but I finally reached the end.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the puzzle after completing the game. In the puzzle subject 16 had a chat with Desmond and that's it. Can anyone suggest, is it all we have to do or is there anything else left with subject 16 stuff.